# IntelliJ Live Templates bug with completeSmart() function

Tags: android, templates, intellij-idea, android-studio, live-templates

I am trying to create a Live-Template in Android Studio that will somewhat speed up creation of `findViewById(...)`

Part of it is self-learning, and part is curious in creating such live-templates.

I want to be able to type in the following...

`Button find` + (enter)

...and that should create something like this...

`Button btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddition);`

---

**My current implementation has issues...**

[image]
[image]

...and these issues stem from the use of `completeSmart()`. Whenever you use `completeSmart()`, the template ignores everything after that call and ends editing.

**For example, If I moved the `CAST` named-variable up one slot (above `ID`)**, then the cast would be automatically filled out and it would not let me easily edit `ID` anymore. Same as below picture, but without `btnAddition`. Just `...findViewById(R.id.);`

**With my current setup, I have `CAST` on the very bottom** so I can easily edit all of the named-variables; however, the use of `completeSmart()` does not let the template end (Place the cursor by the `$END$` marker - Line 29 in the picture below) when I am complete.

**Instead, it places the cursor right after the cast**, like so...
[image]

...when it should be placed on the start of the next line. This template does put a new line in, but the cursor does not go there at the end. **Why?**

---

So I want this...

1 ) Since I already but in `Button`, I want to cast to be `Button`. I should not have to type in in twice!

Answer (score 0):

you should use method typeOfVariable()

you can change like this:

[image: foo]